# Encode/compress sequence of repeating integers

Tags: php, javascript, sequence, encode, compression

I have very long integer sequences that look like this (arbitrary length!):

```
0000000001110002220033333
```

Now I need some algorithm to convert this string into something compressed like

```
a9b3a3c3a2d5
```

Which means "a 9 times, then b 3 times, then a 3 times" and so on, where "a" stands for 0, "b" for 1, "c" for 2 and "d" for 3.

How would you do that?
So far nothing suitable came to my mind, and I had no luck with google because I didn't really know what to search for. What is this kind of encoding / compression called?

PS: I am going to do the encoding with **PHP**, and the decoding in **JavaScript**.

**Edit**: Thank you all!

I ended up with this function for encoding:

```
protected function numStringToRle($s){          
        $rle    = '';
        $count = 1;
        $len    = strlen($s);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
            if($i != $len && isset($s[$i+1]) && $s[$i] == $s[$i+1]){
                $count++;                
            } else {
                $rle .= chr($s[$i] + 97).( $count == 1 ? '' : $count);                                
                $count = 1;
            }
        }
        return $rle;            
}
```

And that for decoding:

```
var decodeCoords = function(str) {

   str = str.replace(/(.)(\d+)/g, function(_, x, n) {
       return new Array(parseInt(n, 10) + 1).join(x);
   });

   return str.
     replace(/a/g, '0').
     replace(/b/g, '1').
     replace(/c/g, '2').
     replace(/d/g, '3');     
};
```

Comment: What exactly are you using this for? Are you sure you can't just compress it using Gzip? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip

It will be more efficient time and space wise, and it's already done for you.

Comment: gzip is not an option because I need to decode it with javascript. I am using it as a sort of a bitmask for a 2d game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Basic encoder in PHP:

```
function numStringToRle($s){
    $rle = '';
    $count = 1;
    $len = strlen($s);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ){
        if ( $i != $len && $s[$i] == $s[$i+1] ){
            $count++;                
        }else{
          $rle .= chr($s[$i] + 97).$count;    
          $count = 1;
        }
    }
    return $rle;
}
```

Be warned it will preform badly issues with a string like

```
 123456789123456789
```

If you were going to be handling a string that may have a lot of individual single characters you would be better to add some complexity and not write the length of the run if the length of the run is 1.

```
//change
$rle .= chr($s[$i] + 97).$count;    

//to
$rle .= chr($s[$i] + 97).( $count == 1 ? '' : $count );   

//or
$rle .= chr($s[$i] + 97)
if ( $count != 1 ){
    $rle .= $count;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the name of this algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the `+97`, what does this do, why is it needed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naive implementation of what you want.

```
$toEncode = '0000000001110002220033333';
$currentChar = '-1';
$length = strlen($toEncode);
$encoded = '';
$currentNbrChar = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
  if($toEncode[$i] != $currentChar){
    if($currentChar != '-1'){
      $encoded .= chr(97 + $currentChar).$currentNbrChar;
    }
    $currentNbrChar = 0;
    $currentChar = $toEncode[$i];
  }
  $currentNbrChar ++;
}
if($currentChar != '-1'){
  $encoded .= chr(97 + $currentChar).$currentNbrChar;
}
echo $encoded;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter version:

```
function smush(str) {
  return str.replace(/((.)\2*)/g, function(_, w, x) {
    return x + w.length;
  });
}
```

**edit** oh I see you want to encode with php; sorry I don't know that. Here's a decoder in a similar spirit:

```
function unsmush(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.)(\d+)/g, function(_, x, n) {
    return new Array(parseInt(n, 10) + 1).join(x);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you could probably gzip your data and the browse will automatically unzip it. For most implementations this is going to work better than RLE. But less fun obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="0000000001110002220033333";

//$c will count the number of occurances.

$c=1;

$lastInt=substr($str,0,1);

$str=substr($str,1);

$resultStr='';

$loopEnd=strlen($str);


for($i=1; $i<=$loopEnd+1;$i++)

{

    $nowInt=substr($str,0,1);   
    if($lastInt==$nowInt)
    {
        $c++;
        $str=substr($str,1);
    }
    else
    {
        $char=chr((int)$lastInt + 97);
        $resultStr=$resultStr.$char.$c;
        $str=substr($str,1);
        $c=1;
        $lastInt=$nowInt;
    }
}

// we use if condition since for loop will not take the last integer if it repeats.

if($c>1)
{

$char=chr((int)$lastInt + 97);

$resultStr=$resultStr.$char.$c;

}

echo $resultStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compress( $str) {
$strArr = str_split($str.'0');
$count = 0;
$resStr = '';
$strCheck = $strArr[0];
foreach($strArr as $key => $value)
{
    if($strCheck == $value)
    {
       $count++;
    } 
    else
    {
        if($count == 1)
        {
            $strCheck = $value;
            $resStr .= $strArr[$key-1];
            $count=1;
        }
        elseif($count == 2)
        {
            $strCheck = $value;
            $resStr .= $strArr[$key-1].$strArr[$key-1];
            $count=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $strCheck = $value;
            $resStr .= $strArr[$key-1].$count;
            $count=1;
        }
    } 

} 
return $resStr;
```

}