# Create domain pattern LLLLLLL/NNNNNN shortcut with PHP

Tags: php, dns, str-replace

I want to create a function that shortcut domain name pattern.

The only "law" of the function is that if there is a letter that repeats itself more than 5 times in a row such as LLLLLLL or NNNNNN or even mixed letter LLLLLLLNNNNNN we will get a shortcut in all cases ie 6 times of L sequence will change to L6 and so on in other cases.

Now I want to shorten the domin for example incase the string is 5 letters or numbers in sequence together, I want to create a shortcut.

- For example:

  1. LLLLLLLL -> **L8**
  2. NNLLLLLLLN -> NN**L7**N
  3. LLLLLLLNNNNNN ->
     **L6N6**.

I thought at the first to use "str_replace" function but, the problem is there are infinite examples of shortening.

Comment: Maybe look at [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) which is fairly similar, and so the solutions should be pretty easily adaptable.

Comment: @TZHX perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple `preg_replace` that will utilize a pretty simple pattern to check the sequence. There is also a very similar question here - [Encode/compress sequence of repeating integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566764/encode-compress-sequence-of-repeating-integers)

```
function parseString( $string ) {
    return preg_replace('/(.)\1*/e', 'strlen($0) . $1', $string);
}
```

Then call it like so (passing in the string):

```
echo parseString('NNLLLLLLLNNNLNLNNNN');
```