# Which encoding or encryption algorithm should I use for Query String so that it will result in shortest posssible length (minimum characters)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am not sending any sensitive or security information in the query string.
I am currently using Base64Encoding along with MD5 Hash.
I want to shorten my url as far as possible.

For Eg.:

http://example.com/?Data=U2VhcmNoVHlwZT0yfEJvZHlTdHlsZUlEcz0tMXxUcmFuc0lEPTE0fFRyYW5zVHlwZUlEcz0tMXxGdWVsSUQ9Mzl8RnVlbFR5cGVJRHM9LTF8TWFrZUlEcz0tMXxNb2RlbElEcz0tMXxTb3J0UGFyYW1lbnRlcj1SZXZpZXdDb3VudHxGZWF0dXJlSURzPS0x-swICu07nyN1PmTT897QG%2bA%3d%3d

Comment: `Base64Encoding` adds about 30% to the size of the encoded string. You are better off just using the string as is.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I know that sending as is the best option. But I do not want user to do any manipulation in the query string. So, I am looking for another option to shorten the url as far as possible.

Comment: You can still send as is but append the hash - rehash on the other end and compare the hashes (use a salt so the user can't simply calculate a new hash and send that as well).

Comment: do you just want to display the shortened url or you want to use a shortened one everywhere. if it's the latter one, i think you are looking for something like base36 for alphabets. but keep in mind that not all characters are valid on url so you don't have a lot of options here.

Comment: something to look at... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144704/lossless-compression-method-to-shorten-string-before-base64-encoding-to-make-it

Comment: or http://pp19dd.com/2011/10/query-string-limits-encoding-hundreds-of-checkboxes-with-rle/#demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is not sensitive, you shouldn't be encrypting it, in particular, not if you want to *save* space. Encryption will normally only make the string *longer*.

This is also true to most encodings.

You may want to *compress* the string, using Zip of 7z, which, depending on the size of the string and the variability in it, may give you good results. You can URL encode the resulting `byte[]`.

You will need to test the different options and see what gives you the best results (though simply sending the string as is may be your best option).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind depending on another system, try tinyurl.

http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://example.com?Data=blahblah

Comment: Do you understand that the tinyurl make redirect to the same huge url ? The tinyurl is not shorten the url, is just a shortcut for hidden url, or write them down more easy, or type them on some page. The tiny url is not short the real url.

Comment: @Aristors, valid point. but i was assuming OP just want to display the url so tinyurl makes it look cleaner.

Comment: Even so, it's say `Data=`, how dynamic data can be in real time made tinyUrl ? Can you see that this is impossible ?

Comment: @Aristos, it's possible. first, construct the full url. second, make a http request to tinyurl.com with the url. lastly, receive the http response from tinyurl and the short url is there to use.

Comment: @RayCheng I am looking to shortened dynamic URL QueryString. I am not looking for any sort of redirection using short url.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal, what's the original form of "Data"? is it binary or plain string?