# long alphabetical strjng to short strings compression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that has dynamically loadded elements. These elements will increase in future.

My concern is if IE 7 and 8 will not support very long `GET` urls. I could do a `POST`, but `GET` is much faster.

What I am looking for is a compressor that can take alphabetical strings and turn them into numerical digits. In JS so the get redirect would be like

```
example.com/abc.php?6=1&2=0&3=1&4=2&5=1
```

The values would be either 0, 1, 2 or on for check boxes.

Please share your thoughts on how we can acheive this?

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by `GET` is much faster?

Comment: Chris - POST sends two headers where as GET sends 1 header. Which is why GET requests are faster.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't intended to be an answer, but some links to check:

[An efficient compression algorithm for short text strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138345/best-compression-algorithm-for-short-text-strings)

[String compression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570333/string-compression-in-javascript)

[lz-string javascript string compression](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)

[...or perhaps AJAX over to a PHP routine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)