# How to encode a big string into a small string then decode again in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, decode, encode

I have a very big string and want to encode it in a smaller one. Then I want to decode it again. How to do this?

Comment: What you are asking for is in general simply impossible by basic information theory. What is possible is to map *some* strings to smaller strings in an invertible way, but at the cost of actually expanding other strings.

Comment: You'll get better results when searching for *compression/decompression*, not encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to achieve `compression` of a string that is bigger in size than you want it to be. This is not as easy as it seems. However, there are some resources available online.

Similar question: [String compression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570333/string-compression-in-javascript)

A JS tool for compression: http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Lempel–Ziv–Welch compression algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch