# Import the module for DecompressionStream

Tags: typescript, webapi

In my React Typescript app, I'm getting this error.

```
webpack compiled with 1 warning
ERROR in src/App.tsx:30:21
TS2304: Cannot find name 'DecompressionStream'.
    28 | const enc = new TextEncoder()
    29 | const dc  = new TextDecoder()
  > 30 | const gunzip  = new DecompressionStream('gzip')
       |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I run a Node script without TypeScript, there is no problem.  The CompressionStream and DecompressionStream exist.  But it seems that when TypeScript checks it (or it's because it's being built as a web app?), it thinks we need to import/require something.

I've tested variants of the following import statements to no avail.

- `import { DecompressionStream } from 'compression-streams'`
- `const DecompressionStream = require('DecompressionStream')`
- `const DecompressionStream = globalThis.DecompressionStream`

All the web documentation I've found around the CompressionStreams API don't mention any module name, so I may be missing something.  I've also looked for a Typescript `@types/` module but there doesn't seem to be one -- maybe this web API is too new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a lack of type definitions (or not only).  Rather, TypeScript is protecting us because neither Firefox nor Safari had CompressionStream or DecompressionStream as of 2023-03-19 (UPDATE September: Now they do!).  So, it's not considered to be in the `globalThis` (even though it's in Node's `globalThis`).

For now, continue using one of the many compression packages.  I went with `pako`, which just works.

Comment: It is supported by the most common browsers now (including FF and Safari): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompressionStream#browser_compatibility However I still have TS error. I would like to use this feature and wouldn't like to use a 3rd party lib. Is it a tsconfig issue from now on?

Comment: It works now, as of September 2023!  Though I also migrated to SvelteKit, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Comment: How did you solve it? I can't make it work in my node app.

Comment: @tengl Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570333/string-compression-in-javascript/75793593#75793593

Comment: @meedstrom I updated Typescript to the latest version and cleared node_modules. After that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular Typescript `new (window as any).CompressionStream('gzip')` works, but a better solution is to add the definitions to the file that is using CompressionStream

```
interface CompressionStream extends GenericTransformStream {  }
type CompressionFormat = "deflate" | "deflate-raw" | "gzip";
declare var CompressionStream: {
  prototype: CompressionStream;
  new(format: CompressionFormat): CompressionStream
}
```