# Gzipping data in GWT

Tags: gwt, compression

I have a GWT application that created an XML structure and then posts this to a servlet. Is it possible to gzip this xml doc on the client side before sending it (I have a filter on the servlet that will decompress it)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could´t find a javascript implementation for gzip, but I found this stackoverflow thread with basically the same discussion about compression in javascript: [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

Maybe you can use some of the suggestions and wrap them with JSNI.