# javascript: uri encoding json makes post data much bigger. Alternative?

Tags: javascript, json

I am posting a large amount of data. I need this to be as small as possible for performance reasons.

My data starts out as JS objects. I then stringify it using json. I then send it in a post.

The thing is that I have a lot of `objects:lists [] and dict {}`, as well as short texts, which are placed in quotes `""` by json.

These are then uri encoded before being posted. I do not do this; the browser does it. I can see the result when I look in the request body.

So, every `[, {,` and `""` is now uri encoded, meaning that my string becomes much longer. In fact, if I compare

```
 alert(          JSON_local.stringify(myStuff).length);
    alert(encodeURI(JSON_local.stringify(myStuff).length);
```

the uri encoded string is 50% larger. That's a lot bigger when the string starts out big.

Am I missing something here? json is standard, but it seems to have a negative side effect for me. is there an alternative to using json? Or am I doing something wrong here? Data alsways has to be send as uri encoded, no?

Comment: what about compressing the data? See more discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102824/how-to-zip-gzip-user-data-in-javascript-before-sending-to-the-server). It should be an easy way to reduce the amount of data sent, without sacrificing the good sides of JSON.

Comment: I've tried https://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/. It has almost no effect.

Comment: The compression issue seems to be that the compressed data includes a lot of commas which also take up a lot of space as %2C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data always has to be send as uri encoded, no?

Not true. This depends on the content type you're sending it.

If you use `x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type when sending it, you need to encode the data. If you use `multipart/form-data`, for example, you do not need to. This has been discussed in more length in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/365237). For considerable amount of data, I don't see any real reason to use x-www-form-urlencoded.

Of course, there is more to it than just changing the content type, you need to supply the mime boundaries then. It does sound to me however that that'd be more efficient for you. From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4:

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.

Comment: That made it 30% faster. Thanks! Now I may also be able to take advantage of compression, which was giving me a lot of commas.