# How can I make an image cycle between multiple frames on hover?

Tags: css

I want to make an image do the following:

1. Start as a static image
2. Cycle through multiple frames when hovering
3. Return to the static image when no longer hovering

Image frames I was working with:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr2Xk.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/yicji.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dGdm.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTQOv.png

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486729/is-there-a-way-to-make-gif-play-on-hover-and-pause-when-mouse-is-out) but could not get it to work (it just displayed nothing, even when copying and pasting the jsfiddle example linked to on that page).

Also is there a way of putting this in an img tag rather than a div one?

Comment: By cycle go you mean spend an nth of a second showing one, then show another etc or more gradual change?

Comment: Honestly either would have been fine, hence my imprecise language. ease-in worked for these purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure CSS solution**

```css
@keyframes zigzag{
    0%{
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/6z28Xcz.png');
    }
    25%{
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/A0d4DL0.png');
    }
    50%{
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/1QOJG9w.png');
    }
    100%{
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zwjr693.png');
    }
}

#logo{
    width: 400px;
    height: 170px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 20%;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/6z28Xcz.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#logo:hover{
    animation: zigzag 2000ms ease-in infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
```