# Compress and decompress data using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, compression

I'm working on a PhoneGap application that uses jQuery and jQuery Mobile. I need a way to compress data somehow (for local storage) and also decompress it using JavaScript/jQuery. So far, the only thing I've seen is jSEND but as far as I know, it only compresses the data and the PHP counterpart is responsible for decompressing. What I need is a local compress / decompress action.

Comment: What for do you need to decompress it? Even with no spaces it will work fine

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood jSEND's usage. Is it not usable for binary data?

Comment: Have you checked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/294297/372643

Comment: You should update your question to indicate you're working with image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no phonegap compression library/plugin. It would be nice solution, unfortunately it would also be platform dependent.

Still there's javascript solution for zip compression: http://stuartk.com/jszip/

With that in mind you can then send it/upload it as a BASE64 string.