# Downloading multiple files and zip - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, archive

Is it possible to download multiple images into the sandbox file system (without the "save as" dialog box, or at-max one saveas dialog)  ?

after downloading them, i'd like to ZIP them into one.. is there any javascript archive library?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can have access to all `contents of resources` in a page(images, js\css files etc) i ain't sure of archiving through JS

Answer (score 6):

You can use [zip.js](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js) for this. 
It does already have API for fetching contents to be zipped from HTTP (cf. [zip.HttpReader](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/core-api.html#zip-reading) constructor) and for writing generated zip on HTML5 filesystem (cf. [zip.FileWriter](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/core-api.html#zip-writer) constructor).

Here is an example using the [filesystem API](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/fs-api.html):

`index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Zip JSON data from the BBC into HTML5 FileSystem</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="zip.js"></script>
  <script src="zip-fs.js"></script>
  <script src="zip-ext.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`example.js` file:

```
// create a zip virtual filesystem
var fs = new zip.fs.FS();

// add some files into the zip filesystem 

// add the "bbc-music.json" file in the root directory
fs.root.addHttpContent("bbc-music.json", 
  "http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/genres/music.json");
// add the "bbc-learning.json" file in the root directory
fs.root.addHttpContent("bbc-learning.json", 
  "http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/genres/learning.json");

// create a file named "test.zip" in the root directory of the HTML5 filesystem 
createFile("test.zip", function(fileEntry) {
  // export the zip content into "test.zip" file
  fs.root.exportFileEntry(fileEntry, function() {
    console.log("done");
  });
});

// function to create a file in the HTML5 temporary filesystem
function createFile(filename, callback) {
  webkitRequestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 4 * 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile(filename, { create : true }, callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: Chrome is where Chrome Extensions usually run in.

Comment: This is old, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to download the created zip. I've got the creation working, but I'm not sure how to find the URL for the created file.

Answer (score 1):

You can access images as regular parts of some web-pages or download them separately by means of `XMLHTTPRequest`s. After this you can zip them in a single archive using [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) JavaScript library. The zip can be stored as a file without a "Save As" dialog (try the example on the site). Though I'm not sure why you need the [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#sandbox).

There exist other JavaScript libraries for zipping, for example, some are mentioned in [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip).

Comment: No. Not the ZIP.. The question was actually - when i download images, can i download the images without the "saveAs" dialogue?

But the example in the site looks simpler than what i've thought... i'l try them first