# How to download, zip and save multiple files with Javascript and get progress?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, zip, download, save-as

I'm creating a Chrome extension that needs to download multiple files (images and/or videos) from a website. These files may have a huge size, so I want to show the download progress to the user. After some research I found that currently a possible solution might be:

1. Download all the files with XMLHttpRequests.
2. When downloaded, zip all the files into one archive with a JavaScript library (eg. JSZip.js, zip.js).
3. Prompt the user to save the zip with SaveAs dialog.

I'm stuck at passage 2), how can I zip the downloaded files?

To understand, here is a code sample:

```
var fileURLs = ['http://www.test.com/img.jpg',...];
var zip = new JSZip();

var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fileURLs.length; i++){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onprogress = calculateAndUpdateProgress;
    xhr.open('GET', fileURLs[i], true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
               var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(response);
            // add downloaded file to zip:
            var fileName = fileURLs[count].substring(fileURLs[count].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            zip.file(fileName, blob_url); // <- here's one problem

            count++;
            if (count == fileURLs.length){
                // all download are completed, create the zip
                var content = zip.generate();

                // then trigger the download link:
                var zipName = 'download.zip';
                var a = document.createElement('a'); 
                a.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
                a.download = zipName;
                a.click();
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function calculateAndUpdateProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        // get download progress by performing some average 
        // calculations with evt.loaded, evt.total and the number
        // of file to download / already downloaded
        ...
        // then update the GUI elements (eg. page-action icon and popup if showed)
        ...
    }
}
```

The upper code generate a downloadable archive containing small corrupted files.
There is also an issue with filename sync: blob object do not contains the file name, so If eg. `fileURLs[0]` takes more time to be downloaded than `fileURLs[1]` names become wrong (inverted)..

NOTE: I know that Chrome has a download API but it's in dev channel so unfortunately it's not a solution now, and I would like to avoid using NPAPI for such a simple task.

Comment: As I read the question, you want to zip all images and provide one zip as a download, right? Then the answer from that other question is 100% applicable. Substitute the URL for a data-URL or blob-URL which you generate using the zip library of your choice. If you want an example, feel free to look in the source code of my [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) extension. `popup.js` shows the code to initiate a download of a generated zip file.

Comment: I see that you've attempted to copy the code from my extension without understanding it, is that correct? If so, read the documentation for zip.js and get back when you're stuck or if something is unclear: http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/core-api.html

Comment: from your extension (useful) I used just the code to trigger the download, the problem is not there, it's with passing downloaded file binary data to the zip library, I don't understand how it has to be done since I haven't found any related documentation.

Comment: In my extension, I'm downloading a zip-compatible file, and immediately presenting it as a download. That's not OK in your case, because you're downloading a image, and want to zip it. I've just found another question which seems **exactly** in line with your original and new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180375/downloading-multiple-files-and-zip-chrome-extension

Comment: I know, I already read that answer, but in that case, if the files are downloaded internally by the zip library (and not with xhr request in my code), how can I obtain informations on download progress to notify the user in case the files take some minutes to be downloaded?

Comment: Where in the question did you state that requirement? Please edit the question to contain all information in advance. Otherwise any solution will only be useful to you, and not to anyone else who happens to jump on this question. Re last question, hint, look at the source code of zip.js: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/blob/master/WebContent/zip-ext.js#L216-L241

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was reminded of this question.. since it has no answers yet, I write a possible solution in case it can be useful to someone else:

- as said, the first problem is with passing blob url to jszip (it does not support blobs but it also does not throw any error to notify that and it successfully generates an archive of corrupted files): to correct this, simply pass a base64 string of the data instead of its blob object url;
- the second problem is with file name synchronization: the easiest workaround here is to download one file at a time instead of using parallels xhr requests.

So, the modified upper code can be:

```
var fileURLs = ['http://www.test.com/img.jpg',...];
var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;

downloadFile(fileURLs[count], onDownloadComplete);


function downloadFile(url, onSuccess) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onprogress = calculateAndUpdateProgress;
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(xhr.response);
}

function onDownloadComplete(blobData){
    if (count < fileURLs.length) {
        blobToBase64(blobData, function(binaryData){
                // add downloaded file to zip:
                var fileName = fileURLs[count].substring(fileURLs[count].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                zip.file(fileName, binaryData, {base64: true});
                if (count < fileURLs.length -1){
                    count++;
                    downloadFile(fileURLs[count], onDownloadCompleted);
                }
                else {
                    // all files have been downloaded, create the zip
                    var content = zip.generate();

                    // then trigger the download link:        
                    var zipName = 'download.zip';
                    var a = document.createElement('a'); 
                    a.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
                    a.download = zipName;
                    a.click();
                }
            });
    }
}

function blobToBase64(blob, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataUrl = reader.result;
        var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
        callback(base64);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

function calculateAndUpdateProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Last note, this solution works quite well if you download few and little files (about less than 1MB as whole size for less than 10 files), in other cases JSZip will crash the browser tab when the archive is going to be generated, so it will be a better choice to use a separated thread for compression (a WebWorker, like zip.js does).

If after that the archive has been generated, the browser still keeps crashing with big files and without reporting any errors, try to trigger the saveAs window without passing binary data, but by passing a blob reference (`a.href = URL.createObjectURL(zippedBlobData);` where `zippedBlobData` is the blob object that refers to the generated archive data);

Comment: but a.href of type "data:application/zip" won't trigger a download, will it? maybe data:attachment can be used in here?

Comment: What would be used if we have to deal with a large file?

Answer (score 9):

My solution using `Axios`, `FileSaver.js` and `JSZip`

```
import JSZip from "jszip";
import axios from "axios";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

const zip = new JSZip();

const fileArr = [
    {
        name: "file1.jpg",
        url: "https://url.com/file1.jpg",
    },
    {
        name: "file2.docx",
        url: "https://url.com/file2.docx",
    },
    {
        name: "file3.pdf",
        url: "https://url.com/file3.pdf",
    },
];

const download = (item) => {
    //download single file as blob and add it to zip archive
    return axios.get(item.url, { responseType: "blob" }).then((resp) => {
        zip.file(item.name, resp.data);
    });
};

//call this function to download all files as ZIP archive
const downloadAll = () => {
    const arrOfFiles = fileArr.map((item) => download(item)); //create array of promises
    Promise.all(arrOfFiles)
        .then(() => {
            //when all promises resolved - save zip file
            zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import JSZip from 'jszip'
import JSZipUtils from 'jszip-utils'
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

const downloadZip = async (urls) => {
      const urlToPromise = (url) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data)
          })
        })
      }

      const getExtension = (binary) => {
        const arr = (new Uint8Array(binary)).subarray(0, 4)
        let hex = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          hex += arr[i].toString(16)
        }
        switch (hex) {
          case '89504e47':
            return 'png'
          case '47494638':
            return 'gif'
          case 'ffd8ffe0':
          case 'ffd8ffe1':
          case 'ffd8ffe2':
          case 'ffd8ffe3':
          case 'ffd8ffe8':
            return 'jpg'
          default:
            return ''
        }
      }

      this.progress = true

      const zip = new JSZip()
      for (const index in urls) {
        const url = urls[index]
        const binary = await urlToPromise(url)
        const extension = getExtension(binary) || url.split('.').pop().split(/#|\?/)[0]
        const filename = `${index}.${extension}`
        zip.file(filename, binary, { binary: true })
      }
      await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
        .then((blob) => {
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'download.zip')
        })
}

downloadZip(['https://example.net/1.jpg', 'https://example.net/some_picture_generator'])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged here because they don't explain how the code answers the question. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it solves the problem, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @guari code, I tested it locally and applied it to the react application, attaching the code for others' reference.

```js
import JSZip from "jszip";
import saveAs from "jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js";

// .......

// download button click event
btnDownloadAudio = record =>{
    let fileURLs = ['https://www.test.com/52f6c50.AMR', 'https://www.test.com/061940.AMR'];
    let count = 0;
    let zip = new JSZip();
    const query = { record, fileURLs, count, zip };
    this.downloadFile(query, this.onDownloadComplete);
}
downloadFile = (query, onSuccess) => {
    const { fileURLs, count, } = query;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onprogress = this.calculateAndUpdateProgress;
    xhr.open('GET', fileURLs[count], true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(query, xhr.response);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
onDownloadComplete = (query, blobData) => {
    let { record, fileURLs, count, zip } = query;
    if (count < fileURLs.length) {
      const _this = this;
      const { audio_list, customer_user_id, } = record;
      this.blobToBase64(blobData, function(binaryData){
        // add downloaded file to zip:
        var sourceFileName = fileURLs[count].substring(fileURLs[count].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        // convert the source file name to the file name to display
        var displayFileName = audio_list[count].seq + sourceFileName.substring(sourceFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
        zip.file(displayFileName, binaryData, {base64: true});
        if (count < fileURLs.length -1){
            count++;
            _this.downloadFile({ ...query, count }, _this.onDownloadComplete);
        }
        else {
            // all files have been downloaded, create the zip
            zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
                // see FileSaver.js
                saveAs(content, `${customer_user_id}.zip`);
            });
        }
      });
    }
}
blobToBase64 = (blob, callback) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataUrl = reader.result;
        var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
        callback(base64);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
calculateAndUpdateProgress = (evt) => {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        // console.log(evt);
    }
}
```