# PHP/Javascript shared compression library

Tags: php, javascript, compression

Is there a compression library that has both PHP and JavaScript implementation, such that I can compress/decompress from/to JavaScript/PHP interchangeably?
I know there are different options to compress data with PHP or JavaScript, the problem is that they store their output with different metadata. This means for example, that if some data is compressed into file output.bin using PHP, once I read output.bin using JavaScript (ajax) there is no way I can decompress that stream.

PS: I'm not looking for compression of HTTP requests, I have a bunch of compressed files (throught PHP) which I need to retrieve and decompress using JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: What compression format?

Comment: Why not let the server do it? Compression algorithms generally aren't the best left to handle by the browser because they can be expensive on the CPU.

Comment: You are right Austin, but I cannot set up any server-side script. My requirements are that I can only retrieve some binary (compressed) file. I cannot hack with HTTP headers, gzlib, URLs and the like. Anyway, DEFLATE would be a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) would fit into your scheme, but it provides fast [zlib](http://zlib.net/) compression and decompression.  php has [zlib as well](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php), so that would meet your requirements.  If you need a zlib clone  written entirely in Javascript, there are several out there that show up in a google search.  However I don't know if any are complete or correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be trickier on the Javascript side than the PHP side, but there's lots of discussion and links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into HTTP-level compression. But if you really want to do this by hand, you could use zlib for example. Both PHP and JS have implementations:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php

https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js