# Text compression for JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

I'm looking for a text (string) compression method that works in JavaScript and PHP, similarly to how it works in JSON. I do not know if there is a similar technology.

For example, I would like to compress text with JavaScript and then decompress it afterwards with PHP in another page.

I apologize in advance if this post seems to be a duplicate, but I have searched and have not found anything similar to what I need. I only found functions that work exclusively in one technology (PHP or JavaScript, not in both.
one example:

```
<script>
var text=aaaaa;
 text=functionForCompress(text){}
 text-> for example 5a
<script>
```

in a page php:

```
$decompresedText=functionForDeCompress(request->data);
$decompresedText -> aaaaa
```

request->data contains variable text of script

Comment: What do you mean by `compression`? JSON is object serialisation, but not compression.

Comment: Check also https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate

Comment: How does it work in JSON? That might help clarify your question; it’s not really clear what you’re asking at the moment.

Comment: Well, whatever happens, I'm sure jQuery will save the day. Dude, sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For javascript compression first download jsmin-php , you can download it from https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php

example php :

```
<?php
require 'jsmin.php';

$jsmin_php = JSMin::minify(file_get_contents("your_javascript_file.js"));

echo $jsmin_php;
?>
```