# How to compress json file

Tags: jquery, json, caching, optimization, compression

I need to develop super fast jquery based searching, I am using json file to get the data, The size of my file is about 20mb. I am only accessing the file once and caching it. Problem is that it takes a lot of time performing the first search. Can i some how compress my json file? so it takes less time to load.

Comment: JSON is not a file system and is not a database. If your file is really 20 MB, compression is not going to help a lot. Consider using server-side database or HTML5/WebSQL(SQLite) on a client

Comment: Server-side is not an option, as the records are too many. And it will take lots of time on every call that a user makes.

Comment: You don't have many options. Even HTML5 storage is typically limited to 10MB or something like that. It has to be combination of both server-side and client-side approaches

Comment: How come your file gets that big? Are you returning the WHOLE database to the client?

Comment: i m caching a database table into json file. The records are over million. And can go to nth number.

Comment: I feel like you have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214042). You should state what is your actual problem (not your chosen way to solve it), and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is hot to decompress in javascript right?

Read [JavaScript: Decompress / inflate /unzip /ungzip strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875020/javascript-decompress-inflate-unzip-ungzip-strings) and [How to decompress gzip xhr response in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586328/how-to-decompress-gzip-xhr-response-in-javascript), the should be something usefull