# Javascript: convert a string to a shorter 6-bit binary representation?

Tags: javascript, string, compression, pack

In Javascript I have a large dictionary consisting only of strings with the letters a to z, A to Z en 0-9.
Because these are 62 characters, each character would only need 6 bits.

I read somewhere that Javascript uses at least 2 bytes per character, so I thought I could save a lot of memory/diskspace by compressing the whole dictionary into a smaller representation, maybe binary or integer.

Could this be done?  I guess I need 2 functions, to convert the strings and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that it's really necessary - just _how_ big is your object?

Comment: the dictionary is about 400.000 words,  about 2 MB uncompressed. I need this to fit into an app, so the smaller, the better...

Comment: Have you thought of serialising the object, converting it to base64 then decoding it in your code?

Comment: I would try the LZW compression of the strings from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip

Comment: deflate works well on text. you can get deflate and inflate for js as part of jszip...