# Download and extract gz file using javascript [ClientSide]

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql, gunzip

I'd like to download a database compressed as a **.gz** file in a **cordova** application and extract it to create a local **WEBSQL** database.

**Is this posible?**

I have the need to do this because my app needs to work offline, besides that this database I have to sync is so big that is unthinkable to download it uncompressed.

This sync only happens one time in my app. So after that is not a big deal.

Thanks in advance!

**PD**: I'm currently downloading each table separately but it takes too long, the code is a mess with all the callbacks and stuff. A compressed file with all data would be much more helpful.

Comment: Combine the files, but let the browser handle the gzip part of it for you. Focus on giving yourself a single file to populate the DB with; the server and browser can negotiate the gzip bit (assuming the server is correctly configured).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

Answer (score 0):

You can find `gz` uncompressors for JavaScript in this question: [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)