# load external resources in d3.js with gzip content-enconding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gzip

I am trying load a large dataset into d3.js by compressing files as gzip, and specifying the "Content-Encoding:gzip" in the request header. The browser doesn't seem to uncompress the gzip file as it is supposed to do. I created jsfiddle containing a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amfy10/9dkvs41n/).

```
d3.text("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/335n5iyhqlx1m3k/exmaple.txt.gz", function(error, text) {
    console.log("compressed: ",text)
}).header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the content encoding is only applied to the HTTP packages content, see [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). From my understanding, it doesn't decrompress a whole file after receiving.

Comment: If so, then how can I uncompress the whole file?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) might help you getting started