# How to compress transfer between selenium client and selenium server

Tags: selenium, compression

My Selenium server runs on a remote server.
I launch my Selenium script from my local PC, which get data from a website.

For example, my Selenium script executes this JS code:

```
JSON.stringify(window.results)
```

It can be about 1 or 2 Mo!

Can I enable a compression on my selenium server, like gzip compression on Apache server?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same question on the screenshot. A base64 encoded full screenshot could be 5MB or even bigger, the transfer between client and server is really slooooow.

Answer (score -1):

[JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

It seems that there isn't a great answer and any that would do large compression might take more time than actually transmitting the file itself.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote... I'm sorry if you don't like the answer but that's how it currently works.