# How to convert gzip encoded response into base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64, gzip

I have an ajax response receiving as Content-Encoding as gzip.

I would like to convert it into base64 encoded string.

[image]

In firefox/firebug Net tab I can open response and see in base64 encoded text.

[image]

As you can see below, firebug can convert response into base64 string.
I can save this file as abc.zip and unzip successfully.
How can I achieve it in JavaScript? (Converting ajax response into base64 string)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to decompress the gzip-encoded string first to get the string in uncompressed form, then you can base64 encode the uncompressed string.

See [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) for info on how to decompress gzip-encoded strings.