# Is there any method to shorten image data URI using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-uri

I have converted a canvas image to data URI using jquery and the data URI is too long, say about  800,000 characters.

Is there any methods for reducing/shortening the length of the data URI?

I need to send the image data via GET/POST method but I got an error message that the string length is too long

Comment: What problems are you running into that makes the URI too long?

Comment: I need to send the image data URI as an attachment via GET/POST method but I got an error message that the string length is too long

Comment: Why can't you just send the binary data?

Comment: 800k characters is about 780 kilobytes of data, or 0.76 megabytes, which shouldn't be a problem at all with a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant.As this is the canvasimagedata(which is a base64 string).If you reduce it,some of the data maybe lost.Base64 itself is fairly compressed.You can check out [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

You can try adjusting the image quality i.e (image/jpeg,value from 0-1)
But this wont reduce it to a great extent.

Answer (score 6):

canvas.toDataURL() support different image types. You could try the different formats or use jpg and decrease the quality:

e.g. for 100% quality:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0)
```

or for 50%:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5)
```

This should reduce the image size and therefore the amount of image data.

Comment: You won't be able to reduce the amount of data by a resonable amount. As already suggested in the other comments: If you use POST for transmission, it shouldn't be a problem