# Unpack the gzip via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I load csv.gz

```
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
var xhr = new XHR();

xhr.open("GET", "addres/file.csv.gz", true);
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log( this.responseText );<----

}
xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert( "Error " + this.status );
}
```

Can I unzip this archive into memory on the client(JS) for further parsing?
How to do it? Help me, please.

It does not work as indicated in the responses. Do not unpack.

Comment: please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)

Comment: I can not use these methods to decode / decompress the string: ϯ (; z2 $ @ ĐDebeUwCF $ ɐI2 (D etc